# Sage integral failing on the Watt Fission Spectrum

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, sage, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate the Watt Fission Spectrum using Sage (the commands are below), but when I did I noticed that the result from the integral does not make sense. The Watt Fission Spectrum is a pdf and when integrated from 0 to 10 should be approximately one (confirmed by Wolfram Alpha). With Sage, when the lower bound is close to 0 the integral is negative, and then jumps positive when the lower bound is closer to 1.

Below is a plot of the integral of the Watt Fission Spectrum with the bounds `x to 10` with `x` from `0 to 1`. The jump is very clear.

How can I correct this, and be confident in the future that  integrals are evaluated correctly?

```
var('o')
assume(x>10)
plot(integral(0.453*exp(-1.036*o)*sinh(sqrt(2.29*o)), (o, x, 10)), (x,0,1))
```

[image: Sage Plot]

Per Robert Dodier's suggestion I have tried integration as follows:

```
map(var, 'abcde')
assume(e-d>0)
foo(a,b,c,d,e) = integral(a*exp(b*o)*sinh(sqrt(c*o)), (o, d, e))
float(foo(*map(QQ, [0.453,-1.036,2.29,0,10])))
```

This still returns a value of -0.0010615612261540579.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why Sage isn't relaying the questions from Maxima, but without those, you can't tell (in Sage) that the result is different depending on the parameters.

Here's a derivation in Maxima. I've rephrased the integral as being from 0 to `x` instead of `x` to 10. Since the integrand is a pdf, we should see the integral go from 0 to 1 as `x` increases.

Original formula.

```
(%i2) foo : 0.453*exp(-1.036*o)*sinh(sqrt(2.29*o)) $
```

Express that with symbols instead of numbers.

```
(%i3) foo1 : a * exp(-b*o) * sinh(sqrt(c*o)) $
```

Forestall some questions from `integrate`. It's not absolutely necessary to do this; `integrate` will just ask additional questions if these assumptions are not given.

```
(%i4) assume (equal (a, ratsimp (0.453)), equal (b, ratsimp (1.036)), equal (c, ratsimp (2.29))) $

rat: replaced 0.453 by 453/1000 = 0.453

rat: replaced 1.036 by 259/250 = 1.036

rat: replaced 2.29 by 229/100 = 2.29
(%i5) assume (x > 0) $
```

Compute the integral. `integrate` asks about `x` in relation to the parameters `a`, `b`, and `c`. I'll give each answer in turn and see what I get. `I1`, `I2`, and `I3` are the results for all answers. I'll answer `p` (positive) first.

```
(%i6) I1 : integrate (foo1, o, 0, x);
Is 4*b^2*x-c positive, negative or zero?

p;
(%o6) a*(-gamma_incomplete(1/2,-(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
        *sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))*sqrt(x)
        /(2*sqrt(b)*abs(2*b*sqrt(x)-sqrt(c)))
        +gamma_incomplete(1/2,-(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
         *c*%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(4*b^(3/2)*abs(2*b*sqrt(x)-sqrt(c)))
        -gamma_incomplete(1/2,(4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)+c)/(4*b))
         *sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(4*b^(3/2))+sqrt(%pi)*sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))/(2*b^(3/2))
        +gamma_incomplete(1,(4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)+c)/(4*b))
         *%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(2*b)
        -gamma_incomplete(1,-(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
         *%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(2*b))
```

Now I'll answer `n` (negative).

```
(%i7) I2 : integrate (foo1, o, 0, x);
Is 4*b^2*x-c positive, negative or zero?

n;
(%o7) a*(-gamma_incomplete(1/2,-(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
        *sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))*sqrt(x)
        /(2*sqrt(b)*abs(2*b*sqrt(x)-sqrt(c)))
        +gamma_incomplete(1/2,-(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
         *c*%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(4*b^(3/2)*abs(2*b*sqrt(x)-sqrt(c)))
        -gamma_incomplete(1/2,(4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)+c)/(4*b))
         *sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(4*b^(3/2))
        +gamma_incomplete(1,(4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)+c)/(4*b))
         *%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(2*b)
        -gamma_incomplete(1,-(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
         *%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(2*b))
```

And now `z` (zero).

```
(%i8) I3 : integrate (foo1, o, 0, x);
Is 4*b^2*x-c positive, negative or zero?

z;
(%o8) a*(-gamma_incomplete(1/2,-(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
        *sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))*sqrt(x)
        /(2*sqrt(b)*abs(2*b*sqrt(x)-sqrt(c)))
        +gamma_incomplete(1/2,-(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
         *c*%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(4*b^(3/2)*abs(2*b*sqrt(x)-sqrt(c)))
        -gamma_incomplete(1/2,(4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)+c)/(4*b))
         *sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(4*b^(3/2))
        +gamma_incomplete(1,(4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)+c)/(4*b))
         *%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(2*b)
        -gamma_incomplete(1,-(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
         *%e^(c/(4*b))
         /(2*b))
```

I can't tell just by looking if, perhaps, some of these results are the same. Let's check.

```
(%i9) is (I1 = I2);
(%o9) false
(%i10) is (I1 = I3);
(%o10) false
(%i11) is (I2 = I3);
(%o11) true
```

OK, so there are two distinct results: `I1` (answered `p`)  and `I2` (answered `n` and `z`). I'll put these two into a single conditional expression, in which the test is the question that `integrate` asked. Note that `c/(4*b^2)` is about 0.533, which appears to be the point at which the plot shown by OP has a jump.

```
(%i12) I : if x < c/(4*b^2) then ''I2 else ''I1;
(%o12) if x < c/(4*b^2)
           then a*(-gamma_incomplete(1/2,
                                     -(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
                  *sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))*sqrt(x)
                  /(2*sqrt(b)*abs(2*b*sqrt(x)-sqrt(c)))
                  +gamma_incomplete(1/2,
                                    -(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
                   *c*%e^(c/(4*b))
                   /(4*b^(3/2)*abs(2*b*sqrt(x)-sqrt(c)))
                  -gamma_incomplete(1/2,(4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)+c)/(4*b))
                   *sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))
                   /(4*b^(3/2))
                  +gamma_incomplete(1,(4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)+c)/(4*b))
                   *%e^(c/(4*b))
                   /(2*b)
                  -gamma_incomplete(1,-(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
                   *%e^(c/(4*b))
                   /(2*b))
           else a*(-gamma_incomplete(1/2,
                                     -(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
                  *sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))*sqrt(x)
                  /(2*sqrt(b)*abs(2*b*sqrt(x)-sqrt(c)))
                  +gamma_incomplete(1/2,
                                    -(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
                   *c*%e^(c/(4*b))
                   /(4*b^(3/2)*abs(2*b*sqrt(x)-sqrt(c)))
                  -gamma_incomplete(1/2,(4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)+c)/(4*b))
                   *sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))
                   /(4*b^(3/2))+sqrt(%pi)*sqrt(c)*%e^(c/(4*b))/(2*b^(3/2))
                  +gamma_incomplete(1,(4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)+c)/(4*b))
                   *%e^(c/(4*b))
                   /(2*b)
                  -gamma_incomplete(1,-(-4*b^2*x+4*b*sqrt(c)*sqrt(x)-c)/(4*b))
                   *%e^(c/(4*b))
                   /(2*b))
```

Now I'll plot that. `plot2d` is evaluated with `a`, `b`, and `c` temporarily bound to the specific values. Plot looks as expected.

```
(%i13) plot2d (I, [x, 0, 10]), a=0.453, b=1.036, c=2.29;
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks! Interesting how those assumptions work. It's a little scary how easy it is to break the integral when you don't know how these systems work in the backend. I'll try and raise the issue with the Sage people that the messages aren't being passed from Maxima

Answer (score 0):

Sage, by default, punts to Maxima to compute integrals. Maxima by itself asks some questions about the signs of a couple of variables and yields different results given different answers to those questions. I guess the questions got lost in the Sage/Maxima interface. Sage can also call Sympy to compute integrals, but I find that Sympy cannot solve this integral.

Bear in mind that Maxima is more comfortable with exact numbers (i.e. integrals and rationals) than inexact (i.e. floats). My advice is to replace the floats with rationals, or symbols (later substituting numerical values for the symbols).

Given the different results, you could piece together a function similar to `if <condition 1> then <result 1> else if <condition 2> then <result 2> else ...`. At present there isn't any good way to do that automatically. (I worked on an experimental package named `noninteractive` but I can't recommend it for general use; it is more reliable to construct the `if--then` yourself.)

Here is a Maxima session showing the first case. You can get the others by giving different answers (positive, negative, zero). I haven't checked the result but sorting out the different cases is the first step.

```
(%i2) foo : 0.453*exp(-1.036*o)*sinh(sqrt(2.29*o)) $
(%i3) bar : ratsimp (foo);

rat: replaced -1.036 by -259/250 = -1.036

rat: replaced 1.513274595042156 by 35244471/23290202 = 1.513274595042156

rat: replaced 0.453 by 453/1000 = 0.453
(%o3) 453*sinh(35244471*sqrt(o)/23290202)*%e^-(259*o/250)/1000
(%i4) I1 : integrate (bar, o, x, 10);
Is 36386982230699133124*x-19408949001091265625 positive, negative or zero?

p;
Is x-344460873305900065615/36386982230699133124 positive, negative or zero?

p;
(%o4) 453*(22027794375*sqrt(10)*%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
                      *gamma_incomplete(1/2,
                                        -(-36386982230699133124*x
                                         +53150092471010944500*sqrt(x)
                                         -19408949001091265625)
                                         /35122569720752059000)*sqrt(x)
          /(2*sqrt(259)*abs(6032162318*sqrt(x)-4405558875))
          -97044745005456328125*sqrt(10)
                               *%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
                               *gamma_incomplete(1/2,
                                                 -(-36386982230699133124*x
                                                  +53150092471010944500
                                                   *sqrt(x)
                                                  -19408949001091265625)
                                                  /35122569720752059000)
           /(46580404*259^(3/2)*abs(6032162318*sqrt(x)-4405558875))
          -125*%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
              *gamma_incomplete(1,
                                (36386982230699133124*x
                                 +53150092471010944500*sqrt(x)
                                 +19408949001091265625)
                                 /35122569720752059000)
           /259
          +125*%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
              *gamma_incomplete(1,
                                -(-36386982230699133124*x
                                 +53150092471010944500*sqrt(x)
                                 -19408949001091265625)
                                 /35122569720752059000)
           /259
          +291127525*10^(3/2)*%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
                    *gamma_incomplete(1,
                                      (106300184942021889*10^(5/2)
                                       +76655754261616519373)
                                       /7024513944150411800)
           /(6032162318*sqrt(10)-4405558875)
          -550694859375*%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
                       *gamma_incomplete(1,
                                         (106300184942021889*10^(5/2)
                                          +76655754261616519373)
                                          /7024513944150411800)
           /(259*(6032162318*sqrt(10)-4405558875))
          -291127525*10^(3/2)*%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
                    *gamma_incomplete(1,
                                      -(106300184942021889*10^(5/2)
                                       -76655754261616519373)
                                       /7024513944150411800)
           /(6032162318*sqrt(10)-4405558875)
          +550694859375*%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
                       *gamma_incomplete(1,
                                         -(106300184942021889*10^(5/2)
                                          -76655754261616519373)
                                          /7024513944150411800)
           /(259*(6032162318*sqrt(10)-4405558875))
          +22027794375*sqrt(10)*%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
                      *gamma_incomplete(1/2,
                                        (36386982230699133124*x
                                         +53150092471010944500*sqrt(x)
                                         +19408949001091265625)
                                         /35122569720752059000)
           /(46580404*259^(3/2))
          -110138971875*%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
                       *gamma_incomplete(1/2,
                                         (106300184942021889*10^(5/2)
                                          +76655754261616519373)
                                          /7024513944150411800)
           /((6032162318*sqrt(10)-4405558875)*sqrt(259))
          +97044745005456328125*sqrt(10)
                               *%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
                               *gamma_incomplete(1/2,
                                                 (106300184942021889*10^(5/2)
                                                  +76655754261616519373)
                                                  /7024513944150411800)
           /(46580404*(6032162318*sqrt(10)-4405558875)*259^(3/2))
          -110138971875*%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
                       *gamma_incomplete(1/2,
                                         -(106300184942021889*10^(5/2)
                                          -76655754261616519373)
                                          /7024513944150411800)
           /((6032162318*sqrt(10)-4405558875)*sqrt(259))
          +97044745005456328125*sqrt(10)
                               *%e^(155271592008730125/280980557766016472)
                               *gamma_incomplete(1/2,
                                                 -(106300184942021889*10^(5/2)
                                                  -76655754261616519373)
                                                  /7024513944150411800)
           /(46580404*(6032162318*sqrt(10)-4405558875)*259^(3/2)))
 /1000
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about using symbols. I have tried it and added some information to my questions. I'm sorry but I didn't quite follow what you were trying to say about `if-then` structures, though.

Comment: @chewsocks I've added another answer which works through the stuff with symbols.